# Angular 4 firebase data observable wrong implementation? data not loading at first time

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, observable, angularfire2

I have a problem with my Angular 4, Firebase, AngularFire ionic app with observable that makes firebase request.

The problem is that the first time i click on the view the cards doesn't load, but if i went to other page and come back and i click again then the images loads with no problem but the first time i clic after ionic serve the cards never loads.

I have 2 providers, the first provider is called from view controller gdm1.ts and the call is:

```
constructor(
private dbCards: CardsProvider,
...
){...}
...
ionViewDidLoad() {
this.cards = this.dbCards.loadcards(9);
}
```

This call the first provider cards.ts:

```
constructor(private dbhDb: FirebaseDbProvider) {}
...

loadcards(colnumber)
{
  this.dbhDb.getCards().first().subscribe(cards=>{  
    this.cards = cards[colnumber].cards;
  });
  return this.cards;
}
```

And cards.ts call the second provider firebase-db.ts:

```
constructor(
  public afDB: AngularFireDatabase, 
  public auth: AuthProvider
) {...}
...
getCards(){
 return this.afDB.list('/cards');;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get all of your codes, but I pretty sure this codes works well. :)

gdm1.ts

```
constructor(
private dbCards: CardsProvider,
...
){...}
...
ionViewDidLoad(cardNum) {
this.cards = this.dbCards.loadcards().subscribe(
    card => {
        //get card info
        this.cards = card[cardNum].cards;
    }
);
}
```

cards.ts:

```
constructor(private dbhDb: FirebaseDbProvider) {}
...

loadcards()
{
  //return observable;
  return this.dbhDb.getCards().first();
}
```

firebase-db.ts:

```
constructor(
  public afDB: AngularFireDatabase, 
  public auth: AuthProvider
) {...}
...
getCards(){
 return this.afDB.list('/cards');;
}
```

PS : 
If you want to define providers to init firebase data and keep data.

And Components call getData function in providers when components need the data.
You should use EventEmitter. then you can get events to update components data whenever firebase data is updated.

Comment: Thanks!! I only have needed to change a little thing and it works.

I have needed to remove the first "this.cards =" because with that i obtained an error about data format. It seems it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the cards before you get the response. You need to return the cards inside the .subscribe().Remember, your code is assync.

```
constructor(private dbhDb: FirebaseDbProvider) {}
...

loadcards(colnumber)
{
  this.dbhDb.getCards().first().subscribe(cards=>{  
    this.cards = cards[colnumber].cards;
  });
  return this.cards;
}
```